# Data Analysis in QGIS - Line Graphs

Tags: qgis

I am looking for a possibility to create line charts in QGIS:
I have production data with a Field Name or ID, a date (year) and a value. I would like to be able to show a line graph of this data for individual polygons.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think it is not possible to create line chart in qgis. Easiest way I think is export table in csv or xls and then create graphs in excel, R or in python. If you are familiar with python you can use pyqgis for selecting features and then matplotlib library for creating graphs.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/207208/55203). My suggestion there was to use d3, which is an option if you can code in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

One of the compelling reason for me to start learning QGIS3 was the new plugin [Data Plotly](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataPlotly/).

You would have noticed it already, perhaps through Anita Graser's earlier blog [Data exploration with Data Plotly for QGIS3](https://anitagraser.com/2017/12/06/data-exploration-with-data-plotly-for-qgis3/).

For details, please visit Matteo Ghetta's (author) GitHub page https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly.

[image]

You will find nice examples of interactive Line charts, Bar charts, and more.

Comment: It took me a while to find your reply, but this looks very interesting. I will explore this plugin. Thanks!