# Load frequency histogram in Print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, histogram

I'm a QGIS-user and I'm looking for a way to add a frequency histogram in the print composer. The aim of it would be to visualize the distribution of values around the defined class borders of a given layer.

Considering QGIS can load such charts for graduated layers (properties > style > histogram), I thought it would be interesting to import them straight into a project's print composer. [image]

Does anyone have ever found a proper way to have this done ? I've come across similar topics, like this one [How to create a histogram legend in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207208/how-to-create-a-histogram-legend-in-qgis-print-composer) ... But in my case the main interest would be to have this fixed quickly and automatically, as this specific kind of chart can already be generated by the program.

Comment: Capture screen and save image, then import image to map composer. Why complicate

Comment: @nagib brings up a good point. Does the histogram need to update dynamically as data in the layer change? If not, I'd also recommend just saving as an image and then importing into the map composer.

Comment: Well I tried it this way already but it looks quite bad as you can guess (print screen image quality + grey frame can't be removed). Also, I would find it useful if it can update dynamically. Indeed, the purpose is to submit several versions of different maps for review, so I was looking for something clean and easy. Thanks for the answers anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

There is a related feature request to [provide an export for the vector classification histogram](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15417).

Answer (score 3):

Mostly, this may be possible with the upcoming QGIS 3.0 version (use the weekly build to try).

QGIS 3.0 with Data plotty plugin;

[image]

Add:
QGIS 2x, you can do the graduated frequency only with the numeric data field.

QGIS 3x with dataplotty, you can even use text field.